# hoisting memory in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, hoisting

I am having a problem with my vars in jasmine tests.

```
var utils = require('./utils');

describe('test', function() {
  it('test 1', function (done) {
    var baseMock = utils.fixtures.base;
    baseMock.campaigns.name ='test 1';
    console.log(baseMock.campaigns.name);
    done();
  });

  it('test 2', function (done) {

    var baseMock = utils.fixtures.base;
    'it should be the original name, but have the name changed in the first test'
    console.log(utils.fixtures.base.campaigns.name);
    done();
  });

});
```

I have a base data mock (utils.fixture.base), which is used in each test. But, when I change some attributes of this mock, this change is reflected in the next test.

How can I get the original mock for each test, with originals attributes?

pd: I'm using an old version of node, with ecma5.

pd2: sorry for my English.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to make a copy of the object, or set the properties back to their old values after every test. This has nothing to do with hoisting - you just share the same object.

Comment: Notice that this is not only a problem during your tests, but probably also for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Since we have no idea what `utils.fixtures.base` contains, it's impossible to tell you definitively what to do, but effectively, you need a way to make a copy of your mock object in each test, so you're not modifying it directly:

```js
var utils = require('./utils');

function buildBaseMock() {
    return makeACopyOf(utils.fixtures.base);
}

describe('test', function() {
  it('test 1', function (done) {
    var baseMock = buildBaseMock();
    baseMock.campaigns.name ='test 1';
    console.log(baseMock.campaigns.name);
    done();
  });

  it('test 2', function (done) {
    var baseMock = buildBaseMock();
    'it should be the original name, but have the name changed in the first test'
    console.log(utils.fixtures.base.campaigns.name);
    done();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to clear your cached require...

```
let module_path = require.resolve("./utils");
delete require.cache[module_path];
```

So you could create a global variable `let utils;` and then, within your describe/suite, place cache clear and require in a beforeEach block like this...

```
beforeEach( ()=>{
    let module_path = require.resolve("./utils");
    delete require.cache[module_path];
    utils = require("./utils");
}
```